# make a more dense (or more populated) cloud of words using python wordcloud

Tags: python, visualization, word-cloud

I can generate a word cloud with my words in it:

```
wc = WordCloud(max_font_size=80, relative_scaling=0.1, margin=10, mask=mask, background_color=DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOUR,collocations=False, max_words=1000).generate(input_unigrams)
```

I observed that `wordcloud` parameters is system dependent. e.g. same setting for `relative_scaling` on 2 different systems doesn't necessary result in the same picture.

1- I have the code from my coworker but when I run it on my system it doesn't generate a word cloud as dense as her. I can make it less dense by `relative_scaling=0.1` but I cannot make it highly dense (as high as my coworkers'). How can I make it highly dense?

2- I noticed that playing around the `margin` doesn't seem to affect the result!
Any recommendation on how to fix this issue?

Please Advise!

EDIT: What I've done so far, I ran the code with various combination of settings for the parameters `max_font_size`, `relative_scaling`, `margin`, and `max_words`
but no fix yet!